# UWP: throw/raise not crashing the application, exception silently ignored

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin.forms, uwp, f#, c#-to-f#

I've found that my application is silently ignoring exceptions and I don't understand why.

I'll explain first the case that works: you create a blank UWP app, then reference an external library (in particular this library is implemented in F#), this way:

```
namespace MyApp.Frontend.UWP
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            MyApp.Frontend.App.Throw(); // <- I insert this here

            var app = new MyApp.Frontend.XF.App();
            LoadApplication(app);
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation of the method `Throw` in the F# side is pretty simple:

```
namespace MyApp.Frontend.XF

open System
open Xamarin.Forms

type App() =
    inherit Application(MainPage = MainPage())

    static member Throw(): unit =
        raise (new Exception ("foo"))

...
```

This works well: the app crashes as expected.

However, if in a Xamarin.Forms app I throw the exception from within an async workflow, later capturing it in order to send it to the main thread (to make sure the app crashes), the exception gets ignored! (its exception type `AggregateException` just gets printed to the output, nothing else). The code for this new version of `Throw` is as follows:

```
namespace MyApp.Frontend.XF

open System.Threading.Tasks
open Xamarin.Forms

type App() =
    inherit Application(MainPage = MainPage())

    static member private CaptureException<'T> (task: Task<'T>) =
        let nextTaskDelegate (prevTask: Task<_>) =
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(fun _ ->
                raise prevTask.Exception
            )
            raise prevTask.Exception
        task.ContinueWith(nextTaskDelegate, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
            |> ignore

    static member Throw(): unit =
        async {
            raise (System.Exception("blah"))
        }
        |> Async.StartAsTask
        |> App.CaptureException

...
```

This method of crashing the app (bringing it to the main thread with `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, and also throwing it in the current thread, just in case) works perfectly fine in other platforms (e.g. Xamarin.Android), but somehow it doesn't in UWP and I'm not sure why. How should I bring the exception to light?

Comment: Probably there is noone who handles the task's result and exception is [unobserved](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/). You can to subscribe to [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.8) to actually catch it. Another way would be to handle the task by waiting for it's result. in C# that can be done via await, in F# I would try to use `Async.AwaitTask` or `Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously` if you cant use `async` block.

Comment: but I'm using an F# API which generates a C# task, see above; and then I await it with Task.ContinueWith, this works fine because if I put debug statements in the continuation it reaches it

Comment: also I don't think this should be an "unobserved exception" cause it's being observed from the moment I inspect the `t.Exception` property

Comment: `Task.ContinueWith` is not the same as `await`, you can try to change it with one of constructs I've mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the same, but it achieves the same result here because it places new work to be done after the task is finished

Comment: Yes, that work is done, but it's done in another Task, because `ContinueWith` returns you another `Task`. And you are ignoring result of that `Task`, as well as exception.

Comment: it's not ignored, the previous task comes as an argument of the ContinueWith function

Comment: @knocte You said that you use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread method in Xamarin.UWP, but it doesn't work?

Comment: I didn't say the bold statement that Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread doesn't work, I say that it doesn't work for raising an exception (in UWP only), check the code and run it yourself if you're doubtful :)